# Changing Table display style in MVC3, razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The below table code in razor in a MVC View, generates a standard table lay out of rows and columns. What I am looking for is a way to style the rows so that they look different....  like a customised divs that have rounded corners and with color etc... Basically I dont want it look like a table at all, I want the data outputted in blocks/chunks (?) (one block for one row).. I hope I am making this easy to understand... for example a typical google page when you search has options on the left to click (for images, news, Videos etc) and once you click on a link the list on the right pane changes with entries .. I want my rows to look like that ..like blocks of data and not as a row and column structure...

```
<table>


  @foreach (var item in Model)
 {

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descr)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
    </td>


</tr>
}
 }

  </table>
```

Comment: You question is not related to ASP.NET MVC. I would recommend you reading some tutorials about CSS which is what allows you to style a web site.

Comment: you are right.. this is not MVC. My bad.. got caught up with razor a lot.. its just syntax I realize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you don't use tables. If you want maximum flexibility, you're better off using `<div>` and `<ul>` elements and styling them accordingly, e.g.:

```
<ul class="item">
    <li>
        <div class="name">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</div>
        <div class="description">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Descr)</div>
        <div class="number">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Number)</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Then you probably do not want to use `<table>` instead you can try to use `<ul>`.

Comment: If you'd like to line up things the way columns line up in a table, you can use any hierarchy (like ul/li or div/span) and apply the style `display: table-row` on the ul or div and `display: table-cell` on the li or span.